# Convergence of density functions of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Various kinds of convergence of random variables are described in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables), but a convergence of density functions is not described. Is it not so interesting?

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X$ be random variables $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_1, f_2, \dots, f$ be those density functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. The convergence of density functions is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n = f$ (a.e.).

Answer (score 2):

The following arguments might explain up to a certain level why convergence of density functions is not very fruitful.

---

It is quite well possible that limit $f$ exists but is not a density function in this situation.

Also if $g$ is a density function then so is every function $g+\mathbf1_A$ where $A$ has zero-measure, and this of the same distribution.

So actually you cannot speak of **the** density function but at most of **a** density function.

Okay, in many cases there is a unique one that is continuous and in that sense canonical, but not always.

In short: density functions are (too) capricious.

Comment: Did you mean $g+1_A$?

Comment: @ashpool Yes, I did. Thank you for attending me. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad but we can draw some interesting conclusions from convergence of densities. In particular $\sup_A |P(X_n \in A)-P(X \in A)| \to 0$ which of course implies convegrence in distribution. However we cannot assert convergence in probability or almost sure convergnce.

Comment: Let me add that the other usual types of convergence do not imply convergence of densities.